# How to implement javascript swiper slider plugin into angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, angularjs-directive, slider

I'm trying to implement a javascript swiper slider plugin into my angular app.

I created a directive and added swiper plugin code into it.

after that i added directive name into html element, there is no errors but slider does not work.

probably problem is with code that trigger swiper plugin

```
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: true
}); 
});
```

already is in directive but I think this is bad place for that...

pure javascript example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/tm0DnUvbxO7IqttxYhi6?p=preview

and modified angular app with this plugin in directive:
http://plnkr.co/edit/l4k3vgbqzHIpCTlzcwr6?p=preview

Comment: You don't need to make a directive for it, because it is pure javascript you can just use is everywhere.

Comment: Thank You for your answer and new knowledge :) I repair this version and it works with directive! Problem was with name of directive, it was app_slider..., after changing that to appslider it works. thanks ones again

Comment: non-directive version works better cause in diective ver. after redirect to /home and coming back to /calculator slider wasn't work....